# Cygwin with Eclipse CDT C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I had installed Eclipse CDT and Cygwin with `gcc`, `gdb`, `gnu` etc packages.

But the include directives (`stdio.h`, `conio.h`) are not resolved, and could not build too:

> Launch failed, Binary not found.

Do I need to install other packages?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to run the C++ tool chain in Cygwin?  This might be tricky, because Eclipse is a Java app and sees native Windows paths, while Cygwin has its own paths for things.  If Eclipse launches Cygwin tools, they will differ on paths.

Comment: See [this](http://www.badprog.com/c-eclipse-installation-of-c-c-development-tools-cdt-and-cygwin-for-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `conio.h` in Linux. Cygwin is a Linux-y environment. See [this](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~pkwong/ECE103_files/Resources/Terminal/CygwinGCC_conio/GygwinGCC_conio_Library.htm)? (Unless I'm misunderstanding something)

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory with the executables (gcc, gdb, etc.) in you PATH? That is usually needed for Eclipse to find and configure the environment to use the toolchain.

Comment: It lists the toolchains- Cygwin, MS Visual C++